# Determine connected components of prediction inside of custom loss metric keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to make a modified binary crossentropy loss function Keras that penalizes the model for a large number of islands in the prediction output. Output is 128x128x128. I have a function that counts the amount of islands in an input numpy array, using measure.label(), and it works perfectly. The problem is when I call this function from inside my loss function, the input that the loss function receives is ALWAYS a None value, and I have no idea what is causing this.

Here's my loss:

```
eps = 2
def custom_binary_crossentropy(y_true,y_pred):
        bc = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

        ytyp_x = K.shape(y_true)[0]

        yt = K.reshape(y_true, (ytyp_x,128,128))
        yp = K.reshape(y_pred, (ytyp_x,128,128))
// after this operation i KNOW that the yp and yt values are 3d like they should be, 
//but when I pass them into the num_islands function they are interpreted as None values. 
//I know this because I filter out the None values in the num_islands function
//and return something different if the input is None

        islands = num_islands(yp,0)
        islands = tf.dtypes.cast(islands,dtype=tf.float32)


        loss = bc*(K.log(islands + eps))
        return(loss)
```

The comments sort of sum up the state of the problem.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does `num_islands` work on Tensors, or numpy arrays or python lists?

Comment: @today num_islands works on numpy arrays, though at the start of the function it converts the input to a numpy array. Would feeding a Tensor into this function (as I am doing) convert it to a numpy array properly?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you ever managed to solve this? I want to accomplish the exact same thing (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968268/counting-the-number-of-components-objects-in-an-array). I figure the problem is that every function in tensorflow needs to be differentiable, which the connect component / label function is not. I'm wondering if an implementation with derivative even exists theoretically. Adding the term to a loss function could be great for certain problems I think.

Comment: @dljve unfortunately not, I never got any further than this, and I just sort of stopped working on it. I'd be interested to hear if you've made any progress.

Comment: @helpidontknowwhatimdoing I will let you know if I ever figure it out. I have found out that skeletenization is possible as a differentiable function, using some smart use of maxpool operations (https://github.com/jocpae/clDice) which I guess is somewhat similar to counting the number of components. But skeletonization doesn't reduce components to single points, but skeletons. I that were the case you could sum the points to get the number of components and have a differentiable function. So it is similar, but still not what I need.